# Jekyll fenced code block kramdown issue

Tags: jekyll, codeblocks, kramdown

I'm struggling with fenced code blocks highlighting. Could you help me to sort out what am I doing wrong?

Code highlighting works well when I use liquid tags: {% highlight lang %}{% endhighlight %}, but this approach breaks lists (it's a known issue).
The thing that bothers me most is that when I use kramdown+rouge syntax it doesn't highlight code at all.

Here's how jekyll parses both ways:

1. Kramdown+rouge syntax

   ````
   ```xml
   <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="some.event" />

       <category android:name="some.event" />
   </intent-filter>
   ```
   ````

   [image: html output for kramdown]
2. Liquid syntax

   ```
   {% highlight xml %}
   <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="some.event" />

       <category android:name="some.event" />
   </intent-filter>
   {% endhighlight %}
   ```

   [image: html output for liquid]

I've tried any combinations of blank lines and spaces before and after code block, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: instead of ``` try ~~~.

Answer (score 1):

The image you linked for the kramdown+rouge result only partially displays what kramdown output (i.e. only `<div ...>...</div>`). However, I'm guessing that the result looks like this:

```
<div class="language-xml highlighter-rouge"><span class="nt">&lt;intent-filter&gt;</span>
<span class="nt">&lt;action</span> <span class="na">android:name=</span><span class="s">"some.event"</span> <span class="nt">/&gt;</span>
<span class="nt">&lt;category</span> <span class="na">android:name=
</span><span class="s">"some.event"</span> <span class="nt">/&gt;</span>
<span class="nt">&lt;/intent-filter&gt;</span>
</div>
```

If it does, the result **is** syntax highlighter by rouge via kramdown. You probably only need to include the correct CSS styles. For doing this, [this blog post](https://benhur07b.github.io/2017/03/25/add-syntax-highlighting-to-your-jekyll-site-with-rouge.html) may help.